# SVG Image missing some layers with Flutter, but appears locally well?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I am using Flutter package to use SVG
[flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)
The problem is that most times the SVG pictures are missing some layers.
And when I try to export the missing layer separately and add it to the code, it also disappears.

I want SVG appear well on mobile

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `flutter_svg` implementation isn't as good as the web browser ones.

- The [`flutter_svg` states](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/blob/20932e20cb779373f7030a029baa177e228336cb/packages/flutter_svg/pubspec.yaml#L2), that it supports SVG 1.1, whereas the SVG 2 standard exists since a long time.
- You can check the compatibility of your SVG using the tool provided from the `flutter_svg` package, as mentioned in its README [Check SVG compatibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#check-svg-compatibility) section.
- If you're using Adobe Illustrator, you may also make sure that your SVG is exported with the settings as recommended in the [Recommended Adobe Illustrator SVG Configuration](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#recommended-adobe-illustrator-svg-configuration) section of the package's README.